# Ruby and ctioga2 issue

Tags: ruby

I am trying to run ctioga2 and I keep getting the same error:

```
bash-4.1$ ctioga2 
/usr/bin/ctioga2:49:in `require': /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ctioga2/plotmaker.rb:646: syntax error, unexpected ')' (SyntaxError)
              ) do |plotmaker, size, options|
               ^
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ctioga2/plotmaker.rb:646: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ctioga2/plotmaker.rb:867: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
from /usr/bin/ctioga2:49
```

Do you guys know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the code base exactly of tioga2. Based on the error message it was expecting an assignment (`=`) and ran into a `|` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruby-1.8 specific bug. It is now fixed in the git repository (commit: [be1cc4b](https://github.com/fourmond/ctioga2/commit/be1cc4bb611093ec842eb674647bc7dc4f2486e0)).

But stackoverflow is not the place to file bug reports for programs, you're lucky I stumbled upon this one.

For `ctioga2`, please use either the bug tracker at sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/p/ctioga2/tickets/ or the one at github if you prefer: https://github.com/fourmond/ctioga2/issues/.